# how to disable asp.net menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using asp menu.I want to disable it and enable it using javascript.
Please help

```
  <asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" DataSourceID="HAPSMainMenu" 
                MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="3" DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="true" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false"
                CssClass="mainMenu" DynamicVerticalOffset="1" DynamicHorizontalOffset="0" 
                OnMenuItemDataBound ="mainMenu_DataBound" Height="18pt" Width="100%"
                 >

                <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="menuItem" Width="125" />
                <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="subMenu" />
                <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="subMenuItem" Width="120pt"  />
                <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="subMenuItemHover" />
                <DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="dynamicselectedStyle" />
                <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="menuHover" ForeColor="midnightblue"/>
                </asp:Menu>
```

I want to disable the whole menu bar with Javascript  and I have the menu Id by using firefox...I was hoping for a statement that would disable the whole menu.

Comment: Please post what you have tried?  Some code chunks, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried placing the `asp:Menu` in a `div` and then disabling the div?

```
<div id="myDiv">
...<asp:Menu ...
</div>
```

Then somewhere on your client code, do this:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

myDiv.disabled = true;
```

Comment: I just  tried it .Yes it does work...but the links are garyed out but if I clik on it the links are working...I want to disable it just like it owuld be disabeled if I open a popup

Comment: You'll need to look at the rendered HTML.  I think the asp:Menu control renders out <ul><li>link1.html</li></ul> type markup.  You could try getElementByTagName("li") and then loop the results and check the .classname property and if it's menuItem then set onclick = null;

Answer (score 1):

Do you have jQuery? Do you want to make the menu disappear?

Maybe something like `$(".mainMenu").hide()`?

Comment: No I dont use Jquery...I dont want to hide the menu...I want the user to be unable to use the menu....buitthe menu should be displayed.

Comment: I want something like document..(menuid).disabled=true;

Comment: Then you should set the `selectable` property to `False`.  Edit: You might want to test if IsPostBack first.

Comment: Can you please give me an example code for using selectable cz I dont see that option in Javascript in the intellisense.